# Using flash api to access WebCam in an ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, flash, rtp

Greetings, 
I'm trying to play with live web cam using  asp.net with C#.
I want to  access/stream web cam content using flash then send the captured streams using Real-time Transport Protocol.

How is possiable to do that?
do you know any simple asp.net application related to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RTMP is available in .NET via WebOrbs (http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-net/overview.html) and FluorineFX (http://www.fluorinefx.com), though I haven't used either of them for RTMP.